# creating max_variables within subqueries

Tags: group-by

I have SQL query:

```
select a.merge_key, a.var1, 
a.var2, 
a.var3,
a.name_of_person,
a.name_of_automobile, 
a.price_of_automobile, b.merge_key as m,
b.var1 as v,
b.var5,
b.var6,
b.var7,
from first_table a
inner join second_table b
on a.merge_key = b.merge_key
where a.var2 > 5
```

I want to make changes to query.

- I want to create new variable COUNT for the a.number_of_automobiles for each unique a.name
- For each unique value of b.merge_key, select row with max(b.var7) before join
- For each unique value of a.merge_key, select row with max(a.var2) before join

I try like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.merge_key, 
    a.var1, 
    a.var2, 
    a.var3, 
    a.name_of_person, 
    a.name_of_automobile, 
    a.price_of_automobile, 
    COUNT(a.name_of_automobile) OVER (PARTITION BY a.name_of_person) as number_of_automobiles, 
    b.var1 as v, 
    b.var5, 
    b.var6, 
    b.var7
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        merge_key, 
        var1, 
        var2, 
        var3, 
        name_of_person, 
        name_of_automobile, 
        price_of_automobile, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY merge_key ORDER BY var2 DESC) as rn
    FROM 
        first_table) a
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        merge_key, 
        var1, 
        var5, 
        var6, 
        var7, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY merge_key ORDER BY var7 DESC) as rn
    FROM 
        second_table) b
    ON a.merge_key = b.merge_key AND a.rn = 1 AND b.rn = 1
WHERE 
    a.var2 > 5;
```

Is it done correctly?

Comment: What database system and version?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)